# Can i count the values of 1 column and distinct count another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this line of code below

```
df.groupby(['ProdName','Year'])['OrderID'].count()
```

I was wondering how can i add another column that would do a distinct count (nunique)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 df.groupby(['ProdName','Year']).agg({'OrderID': count, 'OrderID': nunique})
```